# Activity lag when using ExecutorService

Tags: java, android

I am using multiple threads and ExecutorService to check when all of them finished.The problem is when I call method which init Executor service and execute threads (I call it in onCreate()) I have lag when activity starting. Here is my code:

```
public void test(){
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    executor.execute(new SomeTask());
    executor.execute(new SomeTask());
    executor.execute(new SomeTask());
    executor.shutdown();

    try{
        boolean finshed = executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    if (executor.isTerminated()){
        Toast.makeText(AddVehicleActivity.this,"DONE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}


 private class SomeTask implements Runnable
{
        @Override
        public void run(){
            final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization",SharedPreferencesHelper.getToken())
                    .url("http://sapron.uveee.ru/api/vehicles/marks/get")
                    .build();
        try{
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            }else{
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                MarkResponse resp = gson.fromJson(response.body().charStream(), MarkResponse.class);

                for (int i = 0;i<resp.getData().size();i++){
                    Log.i("SHOWVEH", "onResponse: " + resp.getData().get(i).getImg());
                }
            }
            }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();}

    }

}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you calling the above `test()` method inside the `onCreate()` method of an Actitivty? If so and you are calling it on the UI thread then you are blocking it for 60 seconds because of the call to `executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);` in `test()`. That would be the source of the lag.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan then where should i call it?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan Thought I can call threads anywhere i want because they running not in UI thread

Comment: The call to execute the runnables is fine. It's the call to `awaitTermination(...)` that is not as that call blocks whatever thread the call is made from. You can try removing it and you should notice that the activity no longer lags.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan Thanks it helped. But how I am going to know that all threads completed?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan should i check isShutdown?

Comment: Do you really need to know if they all completed? Usually you can have a callback to the UI thread after the background thread completes its work to updated anything you need to. What is the purpose of the results in `SomeTask`? What will you do with them?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan well they load and parse JSON, then i put arraylists with received results into spinner adapter and show spinners.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106225/discussion-between-anton-kazakov-and-george-mulligan).

Comment: Then I would call a method after parsing that data from the runnable. If the user leaves the activity and it is destroyed then you don't care about the results. By the way an AsyncTask usually helps with this. Have you used that before?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan yes of course i did. But what's wrong with checking isShutdown and if it is just load spinners? I decided to use ServiceExecutor because i thought this way to execute and check all threads completed is the best

Comment: That will return true as soon as you call `executor.shutdown()` and does not mean all threads have completed.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan so how to check they completed without using asynctask  etc. just few threads and executor service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be better to use `AsyncTask` for this so you do not block the UI thread while waiting for all tasks to complete. Since it already has a callback method that executes on the UI thread it simplifies things a bit. Make sure you use the [AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...)) method so the tasks are executed in parallel.

After each task completes you can increment an `int` variable in `onPostExecute()`. Once the variable equals how many tasks you need to complete you will know all tasks are completed and you can update the UI in the activity accordingly.